# Prestashop 1 Click Upgrade: Initial Server Error, Class 'Language' not found

Tags: prestashop, upgrade

I upgraded my prestashop version vom `1.6.1.0` to `1.6.1.16` without any problems with 1 click upgrade tool.
Then I tried it from version 1.6.1.16 to 1.7.2.1, but I get the Error:

```
[Ajax / Server Error for action upgradeDb] textStatus: "error " errorThrown:"Internal Server Error " jqXHR: " "
```

In my Apache log, I found only this line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Language' not found in /www/htdocs/CNUMBER/FOLDER1/admin123/autoupgrade/latest/prestashop/install/upgrade/php/migrate_tabs_17.php on line 54
```

This is Line 54 in migrate_tabs_17.php:

```
$defaultLanguage = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
```

then I tried to my php values like this (in .htacces):

```
upload_max_filesize = 640M
post_max_size = 640M
max_file_uploads = 200
memory_limit = 320M
max_input_vars = 3000
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time = 600
set_time_limit = 600
```

But no changes... same error! All files in `/autoupgrade/latest/prestashop are 777`

I hope someone can help me :-)

My PHP Version: `5.6 CGI`

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue using 1 click upgrade.  After it error'd I had to take a backup and reload the site files to a previous version, which tells me that it was definitely a code issue vs a DB issue.  Once the site files were restored it was fixed to where it was before the upgrade. I'm going to work my way through it now as I try again and I'll post results.

Comment: I know you can't comment, but agree this is not really an answer? if so try to update your answer with results as soon as you can to avoid your answer getting flagged.